# OR query in nested objects ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ElasticSearch version 1.7.5 and I am trying to fetch all documents where missing some fields.

My mapping:

```
...
"participant": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
},
"coordinator": {
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "firstName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "lastName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
}
...
```

I want to query all documents that don't have assigned c**oordinator.id or participant.id** yet.

My query looks like:

```
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "coordinator, participant",
        "query": {
            "constant_score": {
                "filter": {
                    "or": [
                        {
                            "missing": {
                                "field": "coordinator.id"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "missing": {
                                "field": "participant.id"
                            }
                        },
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do OR queries via the bool query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-bool-filter.html

So this query would work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "participant.id"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "missing": {
                "field": "coordinator.id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed that you were using a nested query though the mapping does not state that coordinator and participant are nested field types so that will not work:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-nested-type.html

Setting something as a nested type is only useful when you need to group search terms together so I don't think it is necessary for you.